# Origen de las acepciones coloquiales de "rallar" y "rayar"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, etimología, significado, historia

A menudo tengo dudas sobre cuál de los dos verbos, "rallar" y "rayar", significa qué cosa, y tengo que consultarlo en el diccionario:

> **[rayar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VEy3neE)**
>
> Del lat. *radiāre* 'despedir rayos'.
>
> 1. tr. Hacer o tirar rayas.
>
> **[rallar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=V5MGmE6)**
>
> De *rallo*.
>
> 1. tr. Desmenuzar algo restregándolo con el rallador.

Sin embargo, más que estos significados, me confunden aun más las acepciones coloquiales:

> **rayar**
>
> 5. tr. coloq. Trastornar o volver loco. U. t. c. prnl.
>
> **rallar**
>
> 2. tr. coloq. Molestar, fastidiar con importunidad y pesadez.

Por tanto, ejemplos de uso serían:

> ¿Quieres dejar de **rallarme** ya con ese tema?
>
> Este código me está **rayando**, no logro entender lo que hace.

¿Es posible conocer el origen de ambas expresiones coloquiales? ¿Cómo llegaron estos verbos tan similares a adquirir estos significados también parecidos? Lo digo porque si alguien te importuna con insistencia también te puede volver loco, luego parece que ambas acepciones coloquiales puedan ser intercambiables.

Comment: No tengo referencias, pero sospecho que la acepción coloquial de **rayar** proviene de los antiguos discos de vinilo, que si se rayaban, repetían los mismos segundos, una y otra vez de forma obsesiva (de ahí la forma pronominal **rayarse**). Y **rallar**? quizás del ruido desagradable que se produce al rallar ciertos materiales?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Rayarse` (de *estar rayado*) es un [lunfardismo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NiZ82ll) que aparentemente (yo lo ignoraba) se hizo lo suficientemente popular, al menos en España, para que el DRAE le quitara la marca de localismo. La tenía en la edición anterior:

> [**rayar**.](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?val=rayarse&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)
>   [...]
>   **10.** prnl. coloq. *Arg.*, *Chile* y *Ur.* [**enloquecer**](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=zCjgeoFH8DXX2JrNpg9b) (‖ volverse loco).
>
> <sup>*R.A.E.: Diccionario de la lengua española (2001)*</sup>

El origen está en la analogía del loco con el *disco rayado*, que hace que la púa salte de un lado para el otro, resultando en sonidos incoherentes.

El sitio [Etimologias.dechile.net](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?rayado) dice más o menos lo mismo:

> La palabra RAYADO se usa para describir a alguien "rayado de la cabeza", o sea que transmite siempre la misma loquera. Antiguamente, se escuchaban temas musicales en una vitrola o tocadisco. Este aparato hacia girar un disco que tenía un surco espiral. Sobre este surco se ponía la aguja de un brazo fonocaptor, el cual convertía las vibraciones de la aguja en el surco del disco a sonidos musicales. A veces el disco se rayaba y el surco en vez de ir en forma espiral se convertía en círculo. Esto hacía que se repitiera el mismo sonido en cada rotación del disco. A esa repeti.. a esa repeti... a esa repeti... >> (imaginen eso constantemente, hasta que uno le mueve la aguja y...) irrk >> tición se le llamaba "disco rayado". De ahí la gente empezó a decir "suenas como disco rayado", y de ahí se simplificó a "estás rayado".

Con respecto a `rallar`, la palabra es un cognado del francés [*railler*](http://www.wordreference.com/fres/railler) (burlarse, bromear) y del portugués *ralhar*:

> [**ra·lhar**](https://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/ralhar)
>   *verbo intransitivo*
>   1. Falar em voz alta e em tom de repreensão.
>   2. Repreender gritando.
>
> <sup>*Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013*</sup>

Provienen, según algunos, del latín **ragulare*, de *ragere* (vociferar), y no tienen que ver con el `rallar` del queso rallado, que viene de `rallo` (rallador), y éste del latín *rallum*, derivado de *radere* (raer). <sub>(Corominas y Pascual, *Diccionario Etimológico*)</sub>

Por lo tanto, no existe relación (al menos originalmente) entre el `rallar` de molestar y el de desmenuzar, pero sí entre el primero, el portugués *ralhar*, el francés *railler* y el latín *ragere*.

Comment: Una fantástica y educativa respuesta, ¡muchas gracias!